# Problem with a large table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table that's a little complex. I'll try to explain what I want with a picture of a table from word:
[image: Table from word]

I'm new to latex, so I have two questions. How can I make such table look good? And secondly - how do I make it in LaTex? I've tried the following:

```
\begin{table}[hbr]
\caption{Description}
\label{tbl:hexhcomp}
\centering
\noindent
\def\arraystretch{1.2} 
\begin{tabular}[c]{|l || c| c| c| c| c| c| c| c|}
  \cline{2-7}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &
    \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Thermal\\wheel}}} &
    \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Energy\\wheel}}} &
    \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Fixed\\matrix}}} &
    \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Plate}}} &
    \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Tube}}} &
    \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Run-around}}} &
    \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Heat- pipe}}} &
    \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Membrane}}} \\[15pt]
  \hline
  \hline

  \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright{Sensible efficiency}} & N & N & N & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y \\[15pt]
  \hline
  \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright{Latent efficiency}} & N & N & N & N & Y & Y & Y & Y \\[15pt]
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is there a simpler or more elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: change the first column from `c` to `>{\raggedright}p{3cm}` (you need `array` package) then you can get rid of the `\parbox` similarly you don't need the `\parbox` around the rotated boxes in the first row at all. Apart from that it looks about right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand*\rotbf[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Description}
\label{tbl:hexhcomp}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l *{8}c}
\toprule
     & \rotbf{\specialcell{Thermal\\wheel}} 
     & \rotbf{\specialcell{Energy\\wheel}} 
     & \rotbf{\specialcell{Fixed\\matrix}} 
     & \rotbf{Plate} 
     & \rotbf{Tube} 
     & \rotbf{\specialcell{Run-\\around}} 
     & \rotbf{Heat-pipe} 
     & \rotbf{Membrane} \\
\midrule
\specialcell{Sensible\\efficiency} & N & N & N & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y \\
\specialcell{Latent\\efficiency} & N & N & N & N & Y & Y & Y & Y \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You may always include `\midrule` or `\addlinespace[...]` if you think the readability is suffering. You should do this at the very end in order to see the complete picture.

[image]

Comment: Nice! However, the table will contain at least 9 rows of data (like "Sensible efficiency"). Do you still not think there's a need for \hline-s between the lines?

Is it possible to get the N and Y on the middle of the two lines? Or does that hamper the reading quality?

Comment: @ROLF I made it a bit simpler now. Everything is centered like this and no hard coding is required for the sizes.

Comment: Is there a way to insert vertical lines easily in this code? I just want to see what it looks like.

EDIT: Never mind, I found the {l*{8}c} :)

Comment: How to I remove the gaps that appears when inserting vertical lines?

Comment: @ROLF `booktabs` is not meant to be used with vertical lines. You will have to switch back to your `hline`s

Answer (score 1):

Closer to your original layout than the booktabs answer, but using simpler markup.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbtp]% there is no r, always best to include p
\caption{Description}
\label{tbl:hexhcomp}
\centering
\noindent
\def\arraystretch{3} 
\newcommand\rothd[1]{\makebox[20pt]{%
\rotatebox{90}{\def\arraystretch{1}\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular} }}}
\begin{tabular}%[c] no need for [c] it's the default anyway
{|
>{\raggedright}p{3cm}% instead of l 
|| c| c| c| c| c| c| c| c|}
\hline
  % not needed  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
 &
% \parbox[t]{0.8cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Thermal\\wheel}}} &
 \rothd{Thermal\\wheel}&
 \rothd{Energy\\wheel} &
 \rothd{Fixed\\matrix}& 
\rothd{Plate} &
 \rothd{Tube} &
\rothd{Run-\\around} &
\rothd{Heat-pipe} & 
\rothd{Membrane}
 \\
\hline
\hline

Sensible efficiency & N & N & N & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y \\
\hline
Latent efficiency & N & N & N & N & Y & Y & Y & Y \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```